# Unable to generate code coverage report for Angular application

Tags: angular, typescript, code-coverage, cypress, istanbul

I'm currently using Cypress framework to test my Angular application. I want to generate code coverage report for which I'm using Istanbul library. I have created .babelrc file and added "istanbul" plugins to instrument the code as following:

```
{
  "plugins": ["istanbul"],
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-typescript"]
}
```

I've installed code-coverage library and modified plugins/index.html as follows:

```
 module.exports = (on, config) => {
  require('@cypress/code-coverage/task')(on, config)
  return config
}
```

I've imported the support library in support/index.html as follows:

```
import '@cypress/code-coverage/support'
```

Now when I run cypress, I'm able to see that my test cases are running and spec file is able to cover the code as in this picture:

[image]

However the generated report has 0 statements and functions covered. I have a suspect that covering a spec file is wrong and it should cover the app code instead(when I check window.coverage for appcode it's undefined). However I'm unable to find where to modify this configuration. I've followed all the steps as stated in Cypress documentation.

Comment: 1. Run the tests "npm test"
2. Check the tests, there shouldn't be any broken or failed tests case.

Comment: The path property above includes the `/src` folder, which by convention is where the app code lives. Why do you think this is for a spec file?

Comment: I ran npm test and there are no broken/failed tests.

Comment: @SteveZodiac the /src directory is from the main repo where all my applications are stored, the whole path looks like this:```["E:\\One\\MCIO-CPE-StratusApplications\\src\\applications\\feature-flag-admin\\cypress\\integration\\examples\\featureFlag.spec.js"] ```where the code is covered for spec file instead of actual src file which is ``` ["E:\\One\\MCIO-CPE-StratusApplications\\src\\applications\\feature-flag-admin\\src"]    ```

Comment: Ok, so please confirm the project root is `E:\\One\\MCIO-CPE-StratusApplications\\src\\applications\\feature-flag-admin` and `.babelrc` is in this folder. If so, you have the right structure. Do you have a repo I can look at?

Comment: BTW, the code-coverage library should be excluding spec files from the coverage.json. The only paths you should see are for source files.

Comment: Yes I have both project and ```.babelrc``` in my root directory and here's the link to repo https://github.com/SSP17SCM76B/featureflag-coverage/tree/main

Comment: Also I have excluded spec file in the nyc object inside ```package.json``` file

Comment: Had a look at the repo, it looks like the instrumenting is not working properly, since the `statementMap` property is empty. The two source files don't have any executable code, but presume the other src files listed in `out.json` do have statements. I note `babel-plugin-@stratus/stratus-platformistanbul` is not in `.babelrc`, and something in that plugin (or it's configuration) is causing the problem. Looks like @stratus is a layer on top of Angular, but it's not installable from the npm registry so I can't check into that.

Comment: Thanks for looking into the repo. Yes, Stratus is built on top of Angular and I have the access to that platform. I'll have a look into that.

Comment: But isn't ```istanbul``` enough to cover the code for reports?

Comment: Basically your source will have parts that are not pure javascript and need to be translated by babel before istanbul can figure out what's a statement, function, etc then istanbul can add lines that collect the stats (on the fly when served, not on the disk). Looks like that's what the babel plugin `babel-plugin-@stratus/stratus-platformistanbul` is for, but it needs to be hooked up, probably just add to the plugins array in `.babelrc`.